# How to calculate with input values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm a beginner in JavaScript. I'm trying to make a calculator. But I don't have any idea to deal with calculating input values when the operator button clicked. I want to make it so when the operator buttons are clicked, the input value is cleared, and calculates another value with the previous value.

```
const numericBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".numeric"),
      resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset-btn"),
      operatorBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".operator"),
      input = document.querySelector("input");


//function for numeric button
function NumericClickHandler(event) {
  input.value = input.value + event.target.innerText;
}

function showNums() {
  for(let i = 0; i < numericBtns.length; i++) {
    numericBtns[i].addEventListener('click', NumericClickHandler);
  }
}

//function for reset button
function resetBtnHandler() {
  input.value = '';
}

function resetInput() {
  resetBtn.addEventListener('click', resetBtnHandler);
}

//function for operator button
function operate(operator, a, b) {
  switch (operator) {
    case "+": return a+b;
    case "-": return a-b;
    case "*": return a*b;
    case "/": return a/b;
  }
}

function operatorBtnHandler(event) {
  let inputVal = input.value;
  if (event.target.innerText === "+") {
    
  }
}

function calculate() {
  operatorBtns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', operatorBtnHandler);
  })
}

//initial function
function init() {
  showNums();
  resetInput();
  calculate();
}

init();
```

Comment: And the actual problem/question is?

Answer (score 1):

This basically boils down to getting your `operatorBtnHandler` method right. You can store a `buffer` of the currently calculating number, and the most recent operation (`op`) clicked. Then, every time you click a new operator (including the `=`) you just pass the values to your `operate` method.

```
var buffer = 0;
var op = '';
function operatorBtnHandler(event) {
  let inputVal = parseInt(input.value);
  if(event.target.innerText == '='){
     input.value = operate(op,buffer,inputVal);
     op = '';
     return;
  }
  if(op == '')
      buffer = inputVal
  else{    
    buffer = operate(op,buffer,inputVal);
  }
  op = event.target.innerText;
  input.value = ''
}
```

The last bit of the puzzle is resetting the relevant global variables back to their empty state when you reset.

Live working example below.

```js
const numericBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".numeric"),
      resetBtn = document.querySelector(".reset-btn"),
      operatorBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".operator"),
      input = document.querySelector("input");


//function for numeric button
function NumericClickHandler(event) {
  input.value = input.value + event.target.innerText;
}

function showNums() {
  for(let i = 0; i < numericBtns.length; i++) {
    numericBtns[i].addEventListener('click', NumericClickHandler);
  }
}

//function for reset button
function resetBtnHandler() {
  input.value = '';
  buffer = 0
  op = ''
}

function resetInput() {
  resetBtn.addEventListener('click', resetBtnHandler);
}

//function for operator button
function operate(operator, a, b) {
  switch (operator) {
    case "+": return a+b;
    case "-": return a-b;
    case "*": return a*b;
    case "/": return a/b;
  }
}

var buffer = 0;
var op = '';
function operatorBtnHandler(event) {
  let inputVal = parseInt(input.value);
  if(event.target.innerText == '='){
     input.value = operate(op,buffer,inputVal);
     op = '';
     return;
  }
  if(op == '')
      buffer = inputVal
  else{    
      buffer = operate(op,buffer,inputVal);
  }
  op = event.target.innerText;
  input.value = ''
}

function calculate() {
  operatorBtns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', operatorBtnHandler);
  })
}

//initial function
function init() {
  showNums();
  resetInput();
  calculate();
}

init();
```

```html
<input type="number">
<br>
<button class="reset-btn">R</button>
<button class="operator">+</button>
<button class="operator">-</button>
<button class="operator">*</button>
<button class="operator">/</button>
<button class="operator">=</button>
<br>
<button class="numeric">1</button>
<button class="numeric">2</button>
<button class="numeric">3</button>
<br>
<button class="numeric">4</button>
<button class="numeric">5</button>
<button class="numeric">6</button>
<br>
<button class="numeric">7</button>
<button class="numeric">8</button>
<button class="numeric">9</button>
<br>
<button class="numeric">0</button>
```